# Problem with date on saving "Results Folder"

Tags: c#, date

I have an code that making folder save is like this: `03.19.2020 5.02.59`
But I want something like this: `03.19.2020 4:54:48`. (I mean I want the now date time).

```
public static string ResultsFolder = string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy h/mm/ss}", (object)DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: Not on Windows...

Comment: Feedback: you have three visible questions, scoring -3, -1, -3 (there may be some questions you have deleted, or that have been deleted by trusted users). Although the algorithm is not published, at some point your account will be automatically rate-limited or banned from asking questions. To prevent that happening, you need to: (1) spend more time composing your questions; (2) don't ask a question the moment you are stuck, spend some time on researching the issue, and show your research; (3) trim out chatty and pleading material, this can also attract downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

If using current timestamp can do following. Note that this is not a valid file path on windows.

```
public static string ResultsFolder => DateTime.Now.ToString("MM.dd.yyyy h:mm:ss");
```

Comment: yea but i just want Now Date Time

Comment: your question does not ask for using datetime now

Comment: Yea u sure ok but how to make it now date time?

Comment: Updated answer to use current date time

Comment: Yea i test it out but i get this error: 
```System.NotSupportedException: The given path's format is not supported.at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.EmulateFileIOPermissionChecks(String fullPath) at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectoryHelper(String path, Boolean checkHost)at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(String path)at AIOTOOL.Program.Main(String[] args) in ...```

Comment: Ya like @Alexei Levenkov said can't have that as folder path format on windows

Comment: ohh sure :/ sory for waste of time